# Self Statutory Declaration for CIO who worked in a printing firm

Tags: visa, immigration, australia

I am trying to apply for the 189 visa to move my family to Australia. In the last 8 years I have worked as a part owner of a printing firm as the CIO.

Since my education is in Computer Engineering and my previous 7 years experience had been in core tech/tech consulting, I am wondering how to present client references to ACS for the last 8 years considering the company I worked for and part owned deal with clients who requested printing service and not tech service directly.

Though my responsibility bordered on managing the tech infrastructure and maintaining a set up-time for the companies e-commerce and internal networks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.